# Unity: Use Rigidbody2D's Drag to slow down flying character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a character that gets launched into the air with
 `rb.AddForce(direction * punch_strength_value * punch_strength_total);`

I want this character to be slowed down the higher he is in the air, creating a "soft-limit" so the character does not go too far up. I figured out this could be done by changing the Rigidbodies drag according to the character's height, but I was wrong:

```
 public float height_slowdown = 1;
 void Update()
 {
     heigth = transform.position.y;
     rb.drag = height * height_slowdown;
 }
```

Using this, the character launches into the air and is then slowed down very abruptly as if there was an invisible wall (meaning the X value does not change anymore). He then falls very slowly to the ground.

The character starts at X:0 Y:0 if that's of any help.

How do I make the character to slow down his gain in height the higher he is?

Comment: I'm not a big expert on unity physics but ain't a downward force would help you?

Comment: By default a launched projectile will be only affected by it's **gravity** and drag

Comment: Changing the gravity would make big changes to the whole scene and, afaik, is bad practice, so I don't think this is applicable in my case.

Comment: Did you play with mass?

Comment: I did. `rb.mass = 1 + (heigth * heigth_slowdown);` using this, the character seems to always have a mass of 0.0001 so he launches extremely high. I also tried putting this into `if (rb.mass >= 1)` so it does not go below 1, but that didn't work either.